# Problem 5, Chapter 3. Rudin's functional analysis, point (a) and (b)

Tags: functional-analysis

Need an hint on this exercise, only first two points for now.

> For $0 < p < \infty$, let $l^p$ be the sapce of all functions $x$ (real or complex, as the case may be) on the positive integers, such that
> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x(n)|^p < \infty
> $$
> For $0 \leq p < \infty$. Define $\left\lVert x \right\rVert = \left\{ \sum |x(n)|^p \right\}^{1/p}$, and define $\left\lVert x \right\rVert_{\infty} = \sup_n |x(n)|$. 
> (a) Assume $1 \leq p < \infty$. Prove that $\left\lVert x \right\rVert_p$ and $\left\rVert x \right\rVert_{\infty}$ make $l^p$ and $l^{\infty}$ into Banach Spaces. If $p^{-1} + q^{-1} = 1$, prove that $(l^p)^* = l^q$ in the following sense: There is a one-to-one correspondence $\Lambda \leftrightarrow y$ between $(l^p)^*$ and $l^q$, given by
> $$
> \Lambda x = \sum x(n)y(n) \;\;\; (x \in l^p)
> $$ 
> (b) Assume $1 < p < \infty$ and prove that $l^p$ contains sequences that converge weakly but not strongly.

I think (a) is trivial. Since $L^p(X,\mu)$ is a banach space taking as $\mu$ the counting measure we obtain the result. Likewise Riesz representation with the counting measure $\mu$ gives me the representation of the dual space. 
For (b) I am not sure, my thought was to construct an example of sequence
$$
x_m(n) = \begin{cases}
1 & m \leq n \\
0 & \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}
$$

I ended up with nothing, because I don't know how to show eventually this converges weakly.
(I know that this is probably a standard exercise, my apologies if the question is trivial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $x_m(n)=1$ if $n=m$ and $0$ otherwise. This sequence converges weakly to $0$ becasue $\sum x_m(n)y_n =y_m \to 0$ as $ m \to \infty$ for any $y=(y_n)$ in the dual of $\ell^{p}$ (which is $\ell^{q})$. Of course, this sequence does not converge strongly.

Comment: Right, it was silly. Obviously $y_m$ must go to $0$ otherwise it wouldn't be in $l^q$.